# How to poll multiple pids with monit

Tags: linux

I have a script which spawns mutiple pids, outputting something like:

```
processname.eth4.pid
processname.eth5.pid
processname.eth8.pid
```

Currently i am monitoring indiviual pids like so:

```
check process perl
    with pidfile /var/run/processname.eth4.pid
    start = "/usr/bin/perl /usr/local/etc/script.pl"
    stop = "/bin/cat /var/run/processname.eth4.pid  | /usr/bin/xargs kill -9"
```

Is there a way `monit` can poll multiple pids without using multiple statements for individual pids?

Answer (score 0):

You might use `trap check_children SIGCHLD` to be notified on `SIGCHLD` and define the function `check_children` to detect which of the processes is still living and wich not.

Type `help trap` in bash for more info.